# Razor Pages - I get Invalid ModelType because my hidden field is empty

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

So I have a field (Unit of measurement) that will be hidden if the user chooses the option ''Check-in''.  If the user chooses that option and then uploads the form, the field will be shown, followed by the error ''The UnitOfMeasurement field is required". How can I prevent this from happening? I want that field to be equal to "Done".

If you see the following files, you will notice that there isn't an Id field and that I hardcoded the row for that column (on the SQLite code) yet it works

.cshtml

```
@page
@model MVC.HabitTracker.Pages.CreateHabitModel
@{
}

<h3>Create a habit</h3>
<br />
<p>We do have available habits for you to log, but you can add more!</p>
<br />

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="HabitType.ImagePath" class="control-label">URL of your habit's icon</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="HabitType.ImagePath" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="HabitType.ImagePath" class="text-danger"></span>
        <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
            You must attach a link to the picture of your habit's icon. This site has a lot of icons you can use: <a href="https://icons8.com/icons/">https://icons8.com/icons/</a>
        </small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="HabitType.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="HabitType.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="HabitType.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
            Insert here the name of your habit (i.e.: water drinking, physical activity, coding time).
        </small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" id="measurability">
        <label asp-for="HabitType.Measurability" class="control-label">Select the measurability of your habit</label>
        <select asp-for="HabitType.Measurability" class="form-control" onchange="ToggleUnitOfMeasurement()">
            <option value=" ">Select an option</option>
            <option value="duration">Duration</option>
            <option value="quantifiable">Quantifiable</option>
            <option value="check-in">Check-in</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    
    <div class="form-group" id="unitofmeasurement">
        <label asp-for="HabitType.UnitOfMeasurement" class="control-label">Unit of measurement</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="HabitType.UnitOfMeasurement" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="HabitType.UnitOfMeasurement" class="text-danger"></span>
        <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
            For example, if your habit is about water consumption, you can measure it on <p>bottles, glasses, liters (l), milliliters (ml), etc.</p>
        </small>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success"/>
    </div>

    @{
        
    }
</form>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>



@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function ToggleUnitOfMeasurement(){
            if ($("#measurability option:selected").text().includes("Check-in")){
                $("#unitofmeasurement").hide();
            }
            else{
                $("#unitofmeasurement").show();
            }
        }
    </script>
}
```

cshtml.cs

```
public class CreateHabitModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public CreateHabitModel(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public HabitType HabitType { get; set; }

        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            if (HabitType.Measurability != "Check-in")
            {
                using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    tableCmd.CommandText =
                        $@"INSERT INTO habit_types(Id, ImagePath, Name, Measurability, UnitOfMeasurement)
                    VALUES(1, '{HabitType.ImagePath}', '{HabitType.Name}', '{HabitType.Measurability}', '{HabitType.UnitOfMeasurement}')";

                    tableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            else
            {
                using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    tableCmd.CommandText =
                        $@"INSERT INTO habit_types(Id, ImagePath, Name, UnitOfMeasurement)
                    VALUES(1, '{HabitType.ImagePath}', '{HabitType.Name}', '{HabitType.Measurability}', 'Done')";

                    tableCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Tried to submit a form, but the ModelState wasn't valid and couldn't submit it. I expected it to work, because I inserted the value in the''null'' column with the SQLite query

Answer (score 0):

From your case, If user select `Check-in` option, The `UnitOfMeasurement` will be hidden, So user can't input anything then when you submit the form, The page will show error message and prevent you to submit it. From the backend code, If use select `Check-in` option, you want the value of `UnitOfMeasurement` is `Done`, In my opinion, you can set the default value of  `UnitOfMeasurement`
to `Done`, So that even when the page hidden the `UnitOfMeasurement` field, This property also has the value.

```
public class HabitType 
{
     public HabitType ()
     {
          UnitOfMeasurement  = "Done";
     }
     
     //........
     public string UnitOfMeasurement { get; set; } 
}
```

Backend

```
[BindProperty]
public HabitType HabitType { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnGet()
{
     HabitType = new HabitType();
     return Page();
}
```